# iOS accessibility issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am facing an issue with accessibility implementation in iOS. I have a custom accessibility message which I want the reader to read. The reader does read the custom message BUT ALONG WITH THE MESSAGE IT ADDS ONE WORD "BUTTON" AT THE END. here is my code below:

```
self.privateToggleButton.accessibilityLabel = "Private. Double tap to toggle setting."
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Isn't the normal behaviour?

Comment: SHOUTING much...?

Comment: I don't understand why downvotes occur for this question. 'magicman' is clearly new at VoiceOver. All the downvoters should be a little more comprehensive because, in my view, such a question doesn't deserve this... and, @magicman, when an object is vocalized as a button, it's because VoiceOver recognize it as is thanks to its trait (normal behavior as 'Vladimir Nul' suggested).

Answer (score 1):

If your item is in fact a button, iOS will automatically read out that it is a button as a hint to the user. If the item has some kind of button-like interaction it is recommended you keep this.

But if you really need to get rid of it, you can do so by updating the item's `AccessibilityTraits` and removing `UIAccessibilityTrait.Button`.

(Note my descriptions of the fields and classes are based on Mono, so the actual Swift/Objective C implementation/naming conventions may be different.)

Answer (score 1):

Using a UIButton will cause VoiceOver to default to saying the word "Button" as the accessibility trait. This is useful to visually impaired users who might not necessarily be able to tell that the object they are looking at is a button that accepts user interaction. I recommend that you do not remove this trait because VoiceOver users are usually familiar with hearing the trait following the accessibility label of the object.

However, if you absolutely want to remove the specification of "Button", you can use the following line of code to remove the accessibility trait.

```
self.privateToggleButton.accessibilityTrait = UIAccessibilityTraitNone
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the other answers, the `.button` trait should not be removed, since the control appears to be a toggle and its trait is required to indicate the intent and behaviour of the control to VoiceOver users. Do also ensure that the current state of the button is conveyed.

If you really need to remove a trait, they can be removed from controls using code like this:

```
self.privateToggleButton.accessibilityTraits.remove(.button)
```

Also note that the "Double tap to X" text is a hint string that should be applied to the `accessibilityHint` property and not `accessibilityLabel`.